# Server in C sends a file to client in Java, but the received file is not complete

Tags: java, c, client-server

I am trying to send a text file from a C server to a Java client. I ran my code and noticed that I'm missing the first (8 characters long) word from my original file but I don't know how to fix that.

Server in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define PORT htons(12221)

void ServeConnection(int sock)
{
    char path[512];
    long dl_of_the_file, sent, sent_in_total, read;
    struct stat fileinfo;
    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    FILE* file;

    printf("Give the path to the file: \n");
    memset(path, 0, 512);
    scanf("%s",path);

    if (stat(path, &fileinfo) < 0)
    {
        printf("Child: I can't obtain information about a file\n");
        return;
    }
    if (fileinfo.st_size == 0)
    {
        printf("Child: filesize 0\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Child: filesize : %d\n", fileinfo.st_size);

    dl_of_the_file = fileinfo.st_size;
    sent_in_total = 0;
    file = fopen(path, "rb");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Child: error at opening a file\n");
        return;
    }

    while (sent_in_total < dl_of_the_file)
    {
        read = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, file);
        sent = send(sock, buffer, read, 0);
        if (read != sent)
            break;
        sent_in_total += sent;
        printf("Child: total sent %ld\n", sent_in_total);
    }

    if (sent_in_total == dl_of_the_file)
    {
        printf("Child: file sent ok\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Child: error at sending a file\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
    return;    
}


int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in adr;
    socklen_t dladr = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    int sock_listen, sock_client;
    sock_listen = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    adr.sin_port = PORT;
    adr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(adr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(adr.sin_zero));


    if (bind(sock_listen, (struct sockaddr*) &adr, dladr) < 0)
    {
        printf("Parent: bind failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    listen(sock_listen, 10);
    printf("Server running...\n");

    while(1)
    {
        dladr = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        sock_client = accept(sock_listen, (struct sockaddr*) &adr, &dladr);

        if (sock_client < 0)
        {
            printf("Parent: accept error\n");
            continue;
        }

        printf("Parent: connection from %s:%u\n", 
            inet_ntoa(adr.sin_addr),
            ntohs(adr.sin_port));
        printf("Parent: I'm creating child process\n");


        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            //child
            printf("Child: start serving)\n");
            ServeConnection(sock_client);
            printf("Child: closing socket\n");
            close(sock_client);
            printf("Child: end of the process\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            //parent
            printf("Parent: return to listening)\n");
            continue;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

and client in java:

```
package com.company;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client2 {

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
      Socket socket = new Socket("150.254.79.243", 12221);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        int bytesRead;

        int filesize = 999999999;
        byte [] byteArray  = new byte [filesize];

        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(is);
        long size = clientData.readLong();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/adh/Desktop/test/test2.txt");
         while ( (bytesRead = clientData.read(byteArray, 0, (int) Math.min(byteArray.length, size))) > -1) {
            fos.write(byteArray, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;

        }

        fos.close();
        is.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

The file I was trying to send: "Hello, how are you?"

What I got: "ow are you?"

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the output of the server side peer? You have a lot of debug pritnfs. Show them to us.

Comment: In the meantime, I can say that *C* side you need to manage also negative return values of `fread()` and `send()`. And you should also manage the scenario in which `sent < read`, by sending again `sent - read` bytes before next fread. I finally would avoid calling a variable `read`...

Comment: OT:  regarding: `sock_listen = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`  always check (>=0) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Parent: bind failed\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made to perform this functionality

Comment: The function: `fork()` has three kinds of returned values: 1) <0 means an error occurred  2) ==0 means in the child process  3) >0 means in the parent process.  The posted code is failing to check for and handle the <0 returned value

Comment: when in the parent process, the parent should wait for a child process to exit.  The posted code is failing to do that functionality

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s",path);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. In the current case, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.   2) when using the 'input format specifier' `%s` and/or `%[...]` always use a MAX_CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `read = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, file);
        sent = send(sock, buffer, read, 0);`   the function: `read()` is a well known function and should not be used as a variable name.   the functions: `fread()` and `send()` return type `ssize_t  not `long int`

Comment: regarding: `if (read != sent)
            break;`   Actually, the number of bytes sent can be less than the value in the `read` variable.  This is NOT an error.  Rather it means the code should adjust `read` by the number of bytes sent and call `send()` again.  I.E. a sliding window

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the line

```
long size = clientData.readLong();
```

As per [this](https://tutorialspoint.com/java/io/datainputstream_readlong.htm), it will read the first 8 bytes, resolved to a long value. It looks like you were trying to use that to find the length of the input stream, but it doesn't work like that and I don't think there's a way to get length of an input stream. Usually, you should send that information first in such a code.

Basically, removing that line and setting size to a big value (for now) should resolve your issue, but you should practice sending the length first in such cases later on.